# Spring Boot how to pass configured/dynamic url in @requestMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to pass String value in Spring-Boot `@RequestMapping("/test")`.

I want to pass `String str ="/test"` as String value in `RequestMapping(str)`, please suggest how to read String value in Request Mapping.

Comment: could you validate the response? could be useful for other members, Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This should work
`@RequestMapping("${test.str.value}")` and in your `application.proprties/yml` `test.str.value = /test`

Answer (score 4):

You can use mainly 2 opions:

Option 1:

```
@RequestMapping("/{pathVariable}/yourUrl")
public void yourRequestMethod(@PathVariable("pathVariable")String pathVariable){...}
```

And you should build the request like this:

```
/yourValue/yourUrl
```

Option 2:

```
@RequestMapping("/yourUrl")
public void yourRequestMethod(@RequestParam("test")String test){...}
```

And you should build the request like this:

```
/yourUrl?test=yourValue
```